# How to find which module is using old version of React Native Gesture Handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I have updated all dependencies, gone through every repo and checked, and I shouldn't be using the old react-native-gesture-handler. How can I get rid of this message and make sure everything is updated? This is the warning:

```
 WARN  [react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you're using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system! 
    at PanGestureHandler (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:112776:38)
    at PanGestureHandler (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:154146:34)
    at DrawerView (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:155476:36)
    at DrawerViewBase (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:149464:22)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at GestureHandlerRootView
    at RCTView
    at View
    at SafeAreaProviderCompat (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:151468:24)
    at DrawerView (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:149736:27)
    at DrawerNavigator (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:142028:32)
    at EnsureSingleNavigator (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:144374:24)
    at BaseNavigationContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:142704:28)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:148730:21)
    at NavigationContainerInner (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:148588:26)
    at RNCSafeAreaProvider
    at SafeAreaProvider (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:150455:24)
    at CustomApp (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:141571:47)
    at ThemeContextProvider (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:197023:25)
    at AuthContextProvider (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:238786:25)
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:141842:26)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:78311:36)
    at testAppmobile(RootComponent) (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.testAppmobile.testApp:85577:28)
```

I know it's just a warning, but I'd *like* to get it fixed for good housekeeping purposes.

Comment: Searching through the package-lock.json might help

Comment: I don't see anything. What should I be looking for specifically?

Comment: Just a random idea. If you search for react-native-gesture-handler you might find which module(s) have it as a dependency, which will let you identify what isn't updated properly.

Comment: They're all ^2.3.0. That's what's so weird. I *did* however just redo `npx pod-install` after doing a mishmash of steps, and it seemed to upgrade a lot of things, so I think I'm in the right direction. I wish there was a more 'certain' way of knowing what steps to do, because with RN deps, it's always a guessing-game (at least to me).